# How to set different transparencies for different vertices in iGraph

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to set the transparency / opacity of the vertices in a graph to alpha = 0.5, except for some chosen ones.

I can alter the transparency with

```
vertex.color = adjustcolor(colorvector,alpha)
```

But this will change the transparency / color for all the vertices. How can I change the alpha value for single vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adjust the ones that you want to change.

```
colorvector[NodesToAdjust] = adjustcolor(colorvector[NodesToAdjust],alpha)
vertex.color = colorvector
```

Comment: That was simple. You made my day. Thank you very much.